# CRUD - ajuda com código

Tags: php, mysql, crud

uma empresa pediu pra fazer um teste e mandou fazer um CRUD com Nome, Email, Telefone e Endereço. Seguindo as aulas da parte de CRUD tentei incluir mais dois itens mas não está dando certo. Não sei o que posso estar fazendo errado. Vou colocar os códigos para mostrar.

// BANCO

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.9.0.1
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: localhost:8889
-- Tempo de geração: 07/11/2019 às 17:05
-- Versão do servidor: 5.7.26
-- Versão do PHP: 7.3.8

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Banco de dados: `teste`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estrutura para tabela `tab_teste`
--

CREATE TABLE `tab_teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `telefone` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Índices de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- Índices de tabela `tab_teste`
--
ALTER TABLE `tab_teste`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabelas apagadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de tabela `tab_teste`
--
ALTER TABLE `tab_teste`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

// CRUD

```
<?php
include 'teste.class.php';

$teste = new Teste();
?>

<h1>teste</h1>

<table border="1" width="500">
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nome</th>

    <th>Email</th>

    <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Endereço</th>

</tr>
<?php
$lista = $teste->getAll();
    foreach ($lista as $item):
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $item['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['nome']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['telefone']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $item['endereco']; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>



<?php
class Teste {

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=teste;host=localhost", "root","root");

            }
            public function adicionar($nome, $email, $telefone, $endereco){

                if($this->existeEmail($email) == false){
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO tab_teste (nome, email, telefone, endereco) VALUES (:nome, :email, :telefone, :endereco)";
                    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
                    $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
                    $sql->bindValue(':telefone', $telefone);
                    $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
                    $sql->execute();

                    return true;
                } else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public function getNome($email){
                $sql = "SELECT nome FROM tab_teste WHERE email = :email";
                $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
                $sql->execute();

                if($sql->rowCont() > 0){
                    $info = $sql->fetch();

                    return $info['nome'];
                }else {
                    return '';
                }
            }

            public function getAll(){
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tab_teste";
                $sql = $this->pdo->query($sql);

                if($sql->rowCont() > 0){
                    return $sql->fetchAll();
                }else{

                    return array();
                }
            }

            public function editar($nome, $email) {
                if($this->existeEmail($email) == true){
                    $sql = "UPDATE tab_teste SET nome = :nome WHERE email = :email";
                    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $sql->bindValue(':nome', $nome);
                    $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
                    $sql->bindValue(':telefone', $telefone);
                    $sql->bindValue(':endereco', $endereco);
                    $sql->execute();

                    return true;

                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }

            public function excluir($email){
                if($this->existeEmail($email)){
                    $sql = "DELETE FROM tab_teste WHERE email = :email";
                    $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                    $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
                    $sql->execute();

                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            private function existeEmail($email){
                $sql = "SELECT FROM tab_teste WHERE email = :email";
                $sql = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
                $sql->bindValue(':email', $email);
                $sql->execute();

                if($sql->rowCont() > 0){
                    return true;
                }else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
}
```

Comment: O seu campo "Id" não está definido como auto-incremental. Ou você faz uma função para incrementá-lo a casa Insert, ou você ajusta ele para ser auto-incremental.

Comment: Outra coisa interessante é nos dizer o que exatamente está dando errado. Em qual parte do código e quais as mensagens de erros que aparecem.

Comment: Amigo, obrigado pela ajuda. Eu removi essa parte do código. Vou editar para você ver. Já coloquei auto-increment.

Comment: Tenta também mudar nome das variáveis, onde for as querys (select, insert, etc), ser $sql e onde receber a configuração (`$this->pdo->prepare($sql);`) ser $stmt, quer seria de statement

Comment: Dá um `print_r( $sql->errorInfo() )`, logo após o execute da função `existeEmail `

Comment: Dei o print_r e o resultado foi esse:  Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM tab_teste WHERE email = 'sonwander@yahoo.com.br'' at line 1 )

Comment: @WandersonSilva, essa pergunta possui uma resposta ao problema proposto. Caso essa resposta tenha lhe ajudado considere a aceitá-la como correta. Caso não saiba como aceitar uma resposta leia: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/137387).

Answer (score 1):

O problema pode estar na função existeEmail(), mais precisamente na linha da `query`. Por causa desse erro, é gerado um erro de sintaxe que encerra o script e consequentemente, não está progredindo para o que fazer depois de verificar o e-mail.

```
$sql = "SELECT FROM tab_teste WHERE email = :email";
```

Está faltando você dizer o que quer selecionar. Você deve indicar o nome da coluna logo após a palavra `SELECT` da `query`. Se são todos os dados do registro, coloque o `*`, se for apenas o e-mail, coloque o nome da coluna do e-mail. Deve ficar dessa forma:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tab_teste WHERE email = :email";
```

Ou

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM tab_teste WHERE email = :email";
```

Comment: Eu tenho que completar os parametros? Desta forma: $sql = "SELECT FROM tab_teste WHERE  nome = :nome, email = :email,  etc";

Comment: Editei minha resposta para você entender melhor. O que está faltando é indicar o nome da coluna logo depois da palavra SELECT da query.

Comment: Depois da palavra chave `SELECT` ou vem `*` ou vem o(s) nome(s) do(s) campo(s) que queira selecionar.

Comment: Amigos vou tentar aqui. Obrigado por enquanto.

Comment: Amigos, consegui resolver o problema que tinha aqui. Obrigado pelas dicas. Agora preciso inserir mais de um endereço por nome. Acho que devo usar foreign key não é?